# Environment selector for PyCharm/Intellij IDEA

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using PyCharm as an IDE, but IntelliJ IDEA is an option as well. (Both is Ultimate version) I have a configuration.py where I have to manually update the name of my environment file every time I want to switch.
Smth like this:

```
os.path.join(root.path(), "test.env"))
```

I would use something like a dropdown menu or plugin for this env selection that could update this dynamically. Is there any solution for this? (Like in Java system parameters)

Comment: Why would the code need to know the IDE you're editing with?

Comment: @SkryptX Because if there's a plugin or some solution to handle this from the IDE that would be the most convenient solution imho. But if you have something else in your mind just say it.

Comment: What do you mean, actually? What is the _environment_ you talk about? Is it the IDE? Is it the virtual environment? what is that you are _switching_?

Comment: I mean by the environment the "test.env" file.
I need to change this string every time to "dev.env" or "prod.env"  etc. when I want to change environment. Sorry I wasn't clear at first.

Comment: I think we speak from different things. What does the IDE provide for your project so that the code needs to act accordingly? There are better ways for sure, but I don't really see why you need to switch depending on your IDE. Are those different projects, different buildchains, different whatever.

Comment: @SkryptX I think that what he means is that he's not to change the IDE, but he wants a PyCharm plugin or a IDE property to set up such that he can "select" the execution "environment" he wants to focus on, i.e. development, test or deploy (which I usally call _modes_). Am I correct?

Comment: @DLM Yes, you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above I suggest you take a look at JetBrains builtin Configuration Manager where you can exactly specify the type of environment you want to execute in.

For the way how the configuration can be distinguished between development and production I see two (very common) ways:

- Pythons `argparse` package, where you can just pass a normal command line parameter to the program and it will act accordingly,
  or
- Environment variables define (as the name suggests) variables that you can respond to during runtime depending if a variable is set or has a specific value. That would be with `os.environ['MYPROG_DEBUG']`.

Both these methods are easily set via the Configuration Manager in PyCharm/IntelliJ IDEA. Hope this gives you a direction to search.